# How do I make new fields appear in the form based upon a selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to display the field "Codice Referto" if in the Label "Tipo consenso" i choose the option "Leggi Referto", otherwise I don't want it to be displayed.

```
      Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <div className="form-section">

        <Label for="type" text="Tipo consenso"  />
        <select
        name="rights"
        value={this.state.rights}
        onChange={this.handleInputChange}>
        <option default value="vuoto"></option>
        <option value="Carica Referto">Carica Referto</option>
        <option value="Leggi Referto">Leggi Referto</option>
        </select>

      <Label text="Codice Referto"  />
        <input
        onVisible={this.checkVisibility}
          type="text"
          name="codiceReferto"
          placeholder="Inserire hash referto"
          autoFocus
          onKeyPress={this.onEnter}     //allows you to move to the next panel with the enter key
          value={this.state.codiceReferto}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
```

Comment: Are you using formik form? Also how does your state look like?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope it will help you

```
{
    this.state.rights === 'Leggi Referto' ?
        <div>
            <Label text="Codice Referto" />
            <input
                onVisible={this.checkVisibility}
                type="text"
                name="codiceReferto"
                placeholder="Inserire hash referto"
                autoFocus
                onKeyPress={this.onEnter}     //allows you to move to the next panel with the enter key
                value={this.state.codiceReferto}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            />
        </div> : null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code snippet: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dfwp7f

Change the `this.state.rights === 'WHATEVER TEXT YOU WANT'` to meet your need.

```
        {this.state.rights === 'Carica Referto' && (<>
          <label htmlFor="codiceReferto" text="Codice Referto" />
          <input
            onVisible={this.checkVisibility}
            type="text"
            name="codiceReferto"
            placeholder="Inserire hash referto"
            autoFocus
            onKeyPress={this.onEnter}     //allows you to move to the next panel with the enter key
            value={this.state.codiceReferto}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          /></>)}
```